# Retrieve empty column using ColumnSet

Tags: c#, entity, dynamics-crm, crm

I need to retrieve certain columns of an Entity even if the field is not populated.

I tried (serv is an OrganizationService object) :

```
Entity entity = serv.Retrieve(entityName, entityId, new ColumnSet(true));
```

and

```
Entity entity = serv.Retrieve(entityName, entityId, new ColumnSet(new String[] { "my_column" }));
```

But, "my_column" has not been set yet, so in my object "entity", I can't access to it and get it's type (for exemple).

I do need to get it even if it's empty, because after that, I need to get the entity referenced by this field when it's a lookup.

Hope it makes sense !

Thanks for your replies !

Comment: What is your scenario when field is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Just access the attribute like this:

```
var myLookup = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("my_column");
```

When field "my_column" has not yet been set, `myLookup` will be `null`.

In a succeeding line of code you can set the attribute simply like this:

```
entity["my_column"] = new EntityReference("my_entity", id);
```

Here id is representing a `Guid`. When the attribute is not yet present, it will be created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
myLookup is null, so as expected, it's because "my_column" is not set.
The problem with your second solution is, I don't know in advance the entity, so I can't set it as an EntityReference...

Comment: Can you tell more about the scenario you have in mind? Why/when do you need to have the lookup field populated?

Comment: Basically, I create an entity. All its fields are empty.
Then, I am creating like an "entity editor", and I need, when I want to populate a lookup, set it using values from my UI. To do so, I had to create an EntityReference (as you said) but for that, I need to know the name of the Entity !

My tool is very generic, so the lookup could be link to any entity. Using metadata, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my issue.

Here is how I did if it can help someone :

```
EntityMetadata metadata = EntityAttributeMetadataCache.Instance.Retrieve(entityName);
if (metadata != null)
{
    AttributeMetadata attrMetadata = metadata.Attributes.Where(x => x.LogicalName == fieldName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (attrMetadata is LookupAttributeMetadata)
    {
        LookupAttributeMetadata lookupAttr = (LookupAttributeMetadata)attrMetadata;
        EntityReference er = new EntityReference(lookupAttr.Targets[0], guid);
        return er; 
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)